# Issue while reading a csv file with tab delimiter in Python using built-in csv module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a csv file with tab as delimiter using the built-in csv module. I am able to read the csv file but the problem that I am facing is that if I am trying to access only the "FORM_CODE", the entire row is getting fetched instead of only FORM_CODE value. Becuase of this, I am getting "index out of range" error.

Below is the content of the csv file:

```
FORM_CODE   CUST_NAME   CUST_ADD    CUST_EMAILID
GA12    Deepak  "Cannaught Place New Delhi India"  a@xyz.com
PA46    Manish  "State Street Sydney Australia" b@xyz.com
```

Python code:

```
import csv

fileName = "CsvDirectory/RefFileTabDelimiter.csv"

listOfRows = []
headerFields = []

csvFileObject = open(fileName, 'r')

csvReaderObj = csv.reader(csvFileObject, delimiter='\t')

headerFields = next(csvReaderObj)

for row in csvReaderObj:
    listOfRows.append(row)

print("Total number of rows are:"+str(len(listOfRows)))

for rowData in listOfRows:
    print("======================================")
    print("Form code:"+rowData[0])
    print("Customer name:" + rowData[1])
    print("Address:" + rowData[2])

csvFileObject.close()
```

Actual output:

```
Total number of rows are:2
======================================
Form code:GA12    Deepak  "New Delhi, India"  a@xyz.com
    print("Customer name:" + rowData[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Expected output:

```
Total number of rows are:2
======================================
Form code: GA12
Customer name: Deepak  
Address: Cannaught Place New Delhi India
======================================
Form code:PA46
Customer name: Manish  
Address: State Street Sydney Australia
```

Note: The python version that I am currently using is 3.8.2.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your problem - but only by using spaces instead of tabs in the data file.

I used the exact same code as you but had of course to create the input file locally. In doing so, I had to insert the tab characters manually.

I got the expected result and *no* IndexError.

Only after I replaced all tabs with a space in the line that reads 'GA12    Deepak  "Cannaught Place New Delhi India"   a@xyz.com', I got the same IndexError as you.

Your data file seems to be separated by space, not by tab.

**Update:**

You can now either modify your input file to be separated by tabs. (Do this if you *want* it to be tab-separated.)

Or you can modify your Python script to expect space instead of tab. For this, just replace `delimiter='\t'` with `delimiter=' '`.

*Btw:* While your code should work as it is, I took the freedom of refactoring it a little bit. This is the way, I suggest that it should like:

```py
import csv

filename = "CsvDirectory/RefFileTabDelimiter.csv"

with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    header_fields = next(csv_reader)
    rows = list(csv_reader)

print(f"Total number of rows is: {len(rows)}")

for row in rows:
    print(38 * "=")
    print(f"Form code: {row[0]}")
    print(f"Customer name: {row[1]}")
    print(f"Address: f{row[2]}")
```

Basically I am using `with open` so that we do not have to close the file manually, and I am using f-strings for formatting.

Comment: In the data file if you are using an empty space between the data, then why you have used the delimiter as '\t' in your Python statement: csv_reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'). Are you trying to say that a data file with an empty space as delimiter is the same as a data file with a tab as delimiter.

' ' as delimiter in csv file = '\t' as delimiter in csv file

Because as per my understanding, if we are reading a csv file with an empty space as delimiter, the statement should be something like:

csv_reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ')

Comment: You are of course right. I just do not know if there has been an error in creating the data file or if you chose the wrong delimiter by mistake during creation of your script. I updated the answer to be a bit more clear about this.